# Maven error in IntelliJ but not in command line

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I use the lib as below. How can i solve the issue?

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
   <id>getui-nexus</id>
   <url>http://mvn.gt.igexin.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>


 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gexin.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>gexin-rp-sdk-http</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.7</version>
 </dependency>
```

it show error in IntelliJ but application work well.

[image]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: are the dependencies under the tag <dependencies> ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error; it's warning you that for some reason gexin-rp-sdk-base is appearing (at least) twice as a dependency in your dependency graph.

It is choosing the 4.0.0.12 version.

See [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) for details.